# Popup Box Gallery with Manual Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, gallery

Can you help me with this code? This code opens a gallery popup when someone clicks on an image. It should open different galleries if someone clicks in different images but it doesn't... Can you correct my code so that it will work for different galleries? Thank you!

```js
// Get the image and insert it inside the modal
function imgg(id){
    var modal = document.getElementById(id);
  var modalImg = document.getElementById('mySlides');
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
   function close() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// Sliseshow
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.mySlides {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px -6px #000;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .mySlides {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.w3-btn-floating {
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">


</head>
<body>

<img id="myImg" onClick="imgg('myModal')" src="http://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/story_medium/public/thumbnails/image/2013/07/31/10/A-striped-field-mouse-(Apod.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="200">

<img id="myImg" onClick="imgg('myModal1')"src="http://therivardreport.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Daniel-Chaffin.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="200">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span onclick="close()" class="close">×</span>
 <img class="mySlides" id="img_modal" src="http://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/story_medium/public/thumbnails/image/2013/07/31/10/A-striped-field-mouse-(Apod.jpg" >
 <img class="mySlides" id="img_modal" src="http://interrete.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Miniature-World-of-Insects6.png" >
 <img class="mySlides" id="img_modal" src="http://www.isharearena.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/wallpaper-281049.jpg?d54e04" >
 <img class="mySlides" id="img_modal" src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg?1448476701" >

 <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;left:280px;" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</a>
 <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;right:280px;" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<div id="myModal1" class="modal">
  <span onclick="close()" class="close">×</span>
 <img class="mySlides" id="img_modal" src="http://therivardreport.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Daniel-Chaffin.jpg" >
 <img class="mySlides" id="img_modal" src="http://www.catnipcamera.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/DSCN98911.jpg" >
 <img class="mySlides" id="img_modal" src="http://www.desibucket.com/db2/01/26021/26021.jpg" >

 <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;left:280px;" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</a>
 <a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;right:280px;" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The close button doesn't work beacuse the variabile "modal" is declared into the function 'imgg' so the function 'close' can't use it.